# Generate Multiple PDF files into a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

How do you save webpages into multiple PDF files?

E.g

```
private void printAllPDF(List<Invoice> Invoices)
    {
        string path = "C:/temp/";
        foreach (Invoice inv in Invoices)
        {
            PDF = PrintToPDF("PrintPage.Aspx?InvoiceGUID="+ inv.GUID);
            PDF.SaveAs(path , inv.GUID +".PDF");
        }
    }
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: if you can tell us the problem with this code?

Comment: I understand you want to go from a Page to a PDF. But might I suggest you create a function inside your Invoice class called `public Document GeneratePDF() { /*use iTextSharp to make the PDF */ }`? The results should be much cleaner than trying to go from a webpage (that probably includes lots of navigational elements) to a PDF.

Comment: Im currently taking over a project that already has the Page nicely designed for the invoice filling them up dynamically already.  
I managed to find a dll(SautinSoft.PdfVision) that can help convert webpage to PDF. However it's more like a link to download the pdf, rather than generating the PDF and saving it into a directory.